# kotlinNpmInstall behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, npm-install, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

### I'm trying to build kotlin multiplatfrom project behind corporate proxy connection and got and error:

```
Couldn't find package "webpack@4.42.1" required by "projectName@version" on the npm registry.
```

and so on.. (I'm not listing all the error dependencies, but it got the same message)

I'm using kotlin.gradle.kts

and I have already tried

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=..
systemProp.http.proxyPort=..
...
systemProp.https.proxyHost=..
systemProp.https.proxyPort=..
```

and so on with domain credential ..., it works with gradle wrapper download, or gradle sync.. but not when it come to kotlinNpmInstall..

I tried using public connection from my personal device and works, so I think it still the proxy issue..
is there anything I missed to setup the proxy related to the kotlinNpmInstall ? and is there any kotlin-gradle-dsl approach for this kind of proxy configuration for spesific js build ?

Comment: It your corporate proxy does ssl inspection, it uses a self-sign cert and this is what hurts your npm. You should ask your IT administrator for that. If you have transparent proxy you need to tell npm to trust this cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks like [KT-38067](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38067). As a WA you can configure settings for yarn via `.yarnrc` and `.npmrc` in the project folder.